# curl_close(): is not a valid cURL handle resource ... but WHY?

Tags: php, curl, resources

I'm making a PHP class that handles some traffic with the use of CURL and everything works quite well (except for cookies but hey that's another thing). One thing that doesn't work that great is the curl_close() function though and I have no idea why...

```
$curlSession = &$tamperCurl->getCURLSession();

var_dump($curlSession);
curl_close($curlSession);
die();
```

I previously called curl_exec() and everything worked perfectly. The output this is giving me is:
    resource(6) of type (curl)
    
    **Warning**:  curl_close(): 6 is not a valid cURL handle resource in
    **filename.php** on line **58**

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening? (the var_dump is saying that it's obviously a curl session).

ADDITION:

Because of copyright problems I cannot post the whole TamperData class atm (it will be GPL later).

I have simplified it to this:

```
$tamperCurl = new TamperCurl('test.xml');
echo var_dump($tamperCurl->getCURLSession());
curl_close($tamperCurl->getCURLSession());
die();
```

The constructor of TamperCurl is like this:

```
public function __construct($xmlFilePath, $options=null)    
{
    if($options != null) $this->setOptions($options);

    $this->headerCounter = 0;
    $this->setXMLHeader($xmlFilePath);
    $this->init();
}

public function init($reuseConnection=false,$resetSettings=null)
{
    $this->curlSession = curl_init();
}
```

Again the same output:
    resource(8) of type (curl)
    PHP Warning:  curl_close(): 8 is not a valid cURL handle resource in TamperCurl.php on line 58

Comment: Try removing the `&` from the method call.

Comment: @Briedis - it's not a pointer. And what's up with question marks? One is enough..

Comment: Ok the pointer might be a little confusing, but it's coming out of a class. If I wouldn't use a reference it would simply be copied in the return statement of the get function. Leaving the actual instance variable of the object untouched. (At least that's what I think is happening).

It doesn't matter if I do it with or without a reference though. Even this function inside the class doesn't work for the same reasons as specified above:
 public function __destruct()
 {
  if($this->curlSession != null) curl_close($this->curlSession);
 }

Comment: Have you actually tried to remove the `&`? Please do so and add a second example and it's outcome. I've never seen code that passes around handles as a PHP variable reference. That's why I suggest you try that first, should be very quick to test and it helps to clarify the issue. Additionally you need to post the code of the class you have in `tamperCurl`.

Comment: Ok I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Hm, I am very sorry but it seems that I am a retard. It fails because of the destruct function where I check whether the curl session is null and if not I close it. But it seems that after closing the curl session the variable isn't set to null -_- So it does actually close it. NVM :( Thx for thinking with me though :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eventually the problem turned out to be this:

```
public function __destruct()
{
    if($this->curlSession != null) curl_close($this->curlSession);
}
```

If you have already closed the curlSession, the variable containing the resource isn't set to NULL but it's set to 'unknown type'. So this fixes the problem:

```
public function __destruct()
{
    if(gettype($this->curlSession) == 'resource') curl_close($this->curlSession);
}
```

I'm not sure why but this also fixed my problem with cookies, so it might be that if you try to close an already closed curl session *something* else goes wrong.